# Proper way to query in Hugo using goTemplates with multiple nested arguments, is it possible?

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I'm working with Hugo and have a question regarding where clause. Currently I am doing the following and it works fine. I attempted to add one more where argument and I got the error below:

**Question:** How do I add multiple nested arguments to Hugo where clause. I will continue to test it out in the meantime.

***Error** calling where: can't evaluate the array by no match argument or more than or equal to two arg:uments*

**Works:**

```
{{ range where (where site.Pages "Type" "post") "Params.type" "featured"  }}
                <div class="ph1-ns w-50-ns flex">
                    {{ .Render "li" }}
                </div>
            {{ end }}
        </div>
```

**Fails:**

```
{{ range where (where site.Pages "Type" "post") "Params.type" "featured" "Params.location" "nashville" }}
                    <div class="ph1-ns w-50-ns flex">
                        {{ .Render "li" }}
                    </div>
                {{ end }}
            </div>
```

**Per Hugo:**
*Nest where Clauses
You can also nest where clauses to drill down on lists of content by more than one parameter. The following first grabs all pages in the “blog” section and then ranges through the result of the first where clause and finds all pages that are not featured:*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, after reading some additional information at https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#pkg-overview; I went with the below.

```
<div class="w-100 flex-ns mhn1-ns flex-wrap mb3">
        {{ range where (where site.Pages "Type" "post") "Params.featured" "!=" nil  }}  
        {{ if(eq .Params.location "nashville")}}        
            <div class="ph1-ns w-50-ns flex">
                {{ .Render "li" }}
            </div>
        {{ else}}
         Coming Soon
        {{end}}
        {{end}}
    </div>
```